# trying to figure out 'this' in some js codes

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="button" value="Button 1" id="btn1"  />
<input type="button" value="Button 2" id="btn2"  />
<input type="button" value="Button 3" id="btn3"  onclick="buttonClicked();"/>


<script type="text/javascript">  

  function buttonClicked(){        
    var text = (this === window) ? 'window' : this.id;    
    console.log( text);        
  }

  var button1 = document.getElementById('btn1');  
  var button2 = document.getElementById('btn2');


  button1.onclick = buttonClicked;

  button2.onclick = function(){
    buttonClicked();
  };

</script>
```

Question:

when click button1, shows: `btn1`, click button2 and button3, shows:`window,` why not `btn2`, `btn3`?

Comment: You should read [about the **this** keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: Though the QuirksMode page explains it very well, I'm not entirely sure whether "copying" is the right word. It does not copy the function, just copies a reference to it. The calling context is what sets the `this` reference for the function execution context.

Comment: And you can easily check that the function is not *copied* as `button1.onclick = buttonClicked; console.log(button1.onclick === buttonClicked);` functions are objects and equality comparisons between objects only return true if both references point to the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
button1.onclick = buttonClicked;
```

It shows `btn1` because onclick (a property of button1) now points to `buttonClicked`, so the context of this call is `button1`

```
button2.onclick = function(){
    buttonClicked();
  };
```

It shows `window` because onclick (a property of button2) now points to an anonymous function, and inside that function you call `buttonClicked();` (similar to `window.buttonClicked();`), the context of this call is `window`

Your case with button3:

```
<input type="button" value="Button 3" id="btn3"  onclick="buttonClicked();"/>
```

is equivalent to:

```
btn3.onclick = function(){
    buttonClicked();
}
```

Because when you declare your event handlers inline, the browser will automatically wraps your code inside an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

**Basics**

When a click handler is defined like this:

```
button.onclick = some_function;
```

As the button is clicked, JavaScript will actually run this:

```
some_function.call(button, ...);
```

In other words, a reference to the button element is bound as `this` inside the handler.

**Anonymous function**

Let's look at the definition for the click handler of `button2`:

```
button2.onclick = function() {
    buttonClicked();
}
```

The anonymous function gets bound to the button, but the call to `buttonClicked()` is not bound at all (so it implicitly is bound to the scope of `window`). To achieve the expected results you need to do this:

```
button2.onclick = function() {
    buttonClicked.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

**Inline**

Whatever you write inside the `onclick` attribute is used as the **body** of the click handler. So your code:

```
<input ... onclick="some_function();" />
```

Is equivalent to:

```
button3.onclick = function() {
    some_function();
};
```

As you can see, it will behave the same as `button2`.

**Bonus**

For the fun of it, you could write your inline click handler like this:

```
<input ... onclick="buttonClicked.call(this);" />
```

[**Results**](http://jsbin.com/ayasal/1/)

Btw, writing event handlers inline is not a very good practice and you should look at registering them using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or [attachEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (IE) but note that they behave differently.